# Transfer Text notes taken on a webpage into a word doc

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to HTML/CSS/Javascript etc so forgive me if I totally noob all over the place here. I'll provide as much context as I can to help you understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

I work in IT as an infrastructure incident mgr for a large company. While working incidents, we typically need to contact several people using 2 different web apps, take notes of what transpires in word, who did what to fix A,B,C or look up instructions regarding certain situations. I'm trying to build an application that consolidates all of these under a single pane of glass.

For the purposes of this thread, I'll solely be discussing the notes taking aspect which covers several areas. At my company for reasons outside the scope of this discussion, it was decided that notes would be entered into word and not the ticketing system. Why not something better? Its Above my pay grade, don't really care...

We use a word doc template that has predefined areas that you fill in as the incident progresses. Example:

Incident Ticket(s): INC12345
Problem Ticket(s): PMI12345
Change Ticket(s): etc
Vendor Ticket(s):

Date:   9/18/15
Incident Manager that started incident: Billy Jo
Incident Manager that ended incident:

Summaries:
Subject/Title (from Alert):

---

So I have a text area floated to the right of the page that I would like to do at least 2 things to start with:

1. Have it ask you every line of question in the template that you fill in the values for. i.e **Incident ticket: inc11111**. When you fill in the answer and hit submit, it populates that field in word.
2. There's a notes section at the bottom of the word template. I'm thinking of entering a notes only textarea that strictly populates that part of the template ALONG with timestamps from your computer clock.

I've searched the internet for several hours trying to find something highlighting how you might do this but only see office docs telling you how to copy and paste text into a word doc. Please let me know if you need any specific info

Comment: I think you would need to use the file systems of node js to save data from your web app to a doc. on the computer. It allows you to read to read and write to files

Answer (score 0):

You want to have to your users input data via a web-based form, and you want this to result in creation of a word document. The missing link is the server application in-between.

You would create an HTML form as normal, with whatever fields / inputs / validations you needed. On submitting this form, the data would be sent to your server. Here you would need to implement a server application that accepts form based inputs and generates a file from them (in this case, a word document).

The process of actually generating the word documents is most likely not trivial, but also not impossible. A quick search for generating word docs on the server throws up a few resources:

[Building Server-Side Document Generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735940(v=office.12).aspx)
[Create and Manipulate Word Documents Programmatically Using DocX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660478/Csharp-Create-and-Manipulate-Word-Documents-Progra)
[Generating a Downloadable Word Document in the Browser](http://www.effectiveui.com/blog/2015/02/23/generating-a-downloadable-word-document-in-the-browser/)

Once the document had been created, it could either be offered for download, or automatically emailed somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I found out today I may be losing my job so for now until I learn more holding off on further dev